# pass function f(x,y) as a parameter with y fixed

Tags: c++, pointers

I would like to know if there is any way in c++ to pass to function and other function with some of its parameters fixed.

To explain here an exemple :

```
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>

double myfunc(double x) { return 5*x; }

double gaussian( double x , double s , double v) { return exp( (x-v)*(x-v) / (s*s) ) ; }

double Trapeze1D(const double x_min, const double x_max, double (*fonction)(double) )
{
    double nb_pts = 100.0 ;
    double integrale = 0.0 ;
    double dx = ( x_max - x_min ) / (double) nb_pts ;

    double x_k ;

    while ( k < nb_pts-1 )
    {
        k++;
        x_k = x_min + (double) k * dx ;
        integrale += fonction(x_k) ;
     }    

    integrale *= dx ;
    return integrale ;
}

int main()
{
    cout << Trapeze1D(0.0,1.0,myfunc) << endl ; // <-- works fine
    cout << Trapeze1D(0.0,1.0, gaussian(double , 2,3) ) << endl ; // <-- I would like something like that ...

    // Also tried :
    double tmp(double x) = gaussian(x, 2,3) ; // <-- does not work C++ does not allow definition of function inside function ...
    cout << Trapeze1D(0.0,1.0, tmp) << endl ; 
}
```

My problem is the following, I will have to integrate (the integration method will be much more sophisticated in the end) several different types of functions and many of them depends on parameters like gaussian, polynomial, beta laws ...

I have also tried using class like this:

```
 class gaussian
 {
  public:
     double eval(double x) ;
     void get(double s, double v) ;
  private:
    double s ;
    double v ;
 }

double gaussian::eval(double x){ return exp( (x-v)*(x-v) / (s*s) ) ; }

int main()
{
    gaussian G;
    G.get(1.0,2.0) ;
    cout << Trapeze1D(0.0,1.0,G.eval) << endl ; // <-- error
}
```

but I get the following error: reference to non-static member function must be called

Any help would be highly appreciated.
many thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need `std::function` and `std::bind`.

Comment: @NathanOliver no he doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.  The simplest is one you were actually very close to:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << Trapeze1D(0.0, 1.0, myfunc) << std::endl;

    auto tmp = [](double x){ return gaussian(x, 2, 3); };
    std::cout << Trapeze1D(0.0, 1.0, tmp) << std::endl;
}
```

This creates a temporary lambda function that wraps your gaussian function.  If you aren't familiar with lambdas, this is a temporary version of declaring tmp at the top of the file:

```
double myfunc(double x) { return 5*x; }

double gaussian( double x , double s , double v) { return exp( (x-v)*(x-v) / (s*s) ) ; }

double tmp(double x) { return gaussian(2, 3, x); }
```

If you wanted this to be more flexible, and you were interested in changing `s` and `v` somewhat regularly, you could always make a functor class, but that would involve a bit of work changing your `Trapeze1D` function to either take in a function pointer or a functor:

```
template <typename FuncType>
double Trapeze1D(const double x_min, const double x_max, FuncType fonction)
{
    ...
    integrale += fonction(x_k);
    ...
}

class gaussian_functor
{
public:
    gaussian_functor(double s, double v)
        : m_s(s)
        , m_v(v)
    {}

    double operator() (double x) const { return exp((x - m_v)*(x - m_v) / (m_s*m_s)); }
private:
    double m_s;
    double m_v;
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << Trapeze1D(0.0, 1.0, myfunc) << std::endl;

    gaussian_functor my_functor(2.0, 3.0);
    std::cout << Trapeze1D(0.0, 1.0, my_functor) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why in the definition of function Trapeze1D must be changed from : double (*fonction)(double) to FuncType fonction ?

Comment: Are you familiar with templates?  Changing the definition to be templated as I did above allows taking in any object as `fonction`, as long as the object has a function that is called by passing it a `double` and returns a `double`.  With the templated definition, you can still pass it a function pointer as you were before, and you can pass it a functor as well.

Comment: @PolizziBastien if it did solve your problem, please mark the solution as accepted so the question appears as answered